# Pegar rows que não sejam do usuário logado

Tags: mysql, sql

Possuo uma tabela com colunas `para` e `de` onde eu insiro IDs diferentes em cada uma, porém eu preciso obter o ID do usuário que ENVIOU o pedido para mim, ou seja o ID que não seja igual ao do usuário logado.

```
SELECT `username` FROM all, users WHERE (`de` = 'ID DO USUARIO LOGADO' OR `para` = 'ID DO USUARIO LOGADO') AND (users.idu = chat.from NOT IN (ID DO USUARIO LOGADO) OR users.idu = chat.to NOT IN (ID DO USUARIO LOGADO)) GROUP BY `c_id` order by id desc
```

Dai criei este código, porém ele continua a me retornar o ID do usuário logado e não do que enviou, que esta a ocorrer?

Usei o `NOT IN` para impedir que fosse o ID do usuário logado, mesmo assim não funcionou.

```
Exemplo: 

Tabela ALL

-------------
| de | para |
-------------
|  2 |  1   |
-------------

TABELA USERS

------------------
| idu | username |
------------------
|  1  |  MARCOS  |
------------------
|  2  |  MANUEL  |
------------------

SELECIONA O ROW ONDE (para = USUARIO LOGADO or de = USUARIO LOGADO) e depois vai na tabela USERS e seleciona o usuário que não seja o usuário logado dentre `para` e `de`.

Ou Seja, retornaria -> Manuel
```

Comment: Quais as estruturas de suas tabelas? Seria bom também uns dados de exemplo. Estou com um pouco de dificuldade em entender sua *query*, essa coluna `username` está em qual tabela?

Comment: @mgibsonbr Atualizei, está claro espero.

Answer (score 4):

Pelo que eu entendi, um dos ids (`de` ou `para`) deve ser o do usuário logado, e o outro não, e você quer o outro em **qualquer uma das duas situações**, certo? Há diversas maneiras de fazer isso, mas a mais semanticamente correta na minha opinião seria usando um `union`:

```
select username
from users
where idu in (
    select de from `all` where para = 'ID DO USUARIO LOGADO'
    union
    select para from `all` where de = 'ID DO USUARIO LOGADO'
);
```

[Exemplo no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/215cb9/2). Ou seja, selecione o conjunto onde o usuário logado é o `para`, e faça a união com o conjunto onde o usuário logado é o `de`. Em cada caso, o id que te interessa é o outro. Busque na tabela `users` quem tem esse id.

**Atualização:** uma forma alternativa, sem envolver *subquery*, seria simplesmente trocar a ordem das suas condições; em vez de uma conjunção de disjunções (i.e. `AND` de `OR`s) você fazer o contrário. Isso exigiria no entanto um `join` a mais além do uso de `case`:

```
select case
           when u1.idu = 'ID DO USUARIO LOGADO' then u2.username
           else u1.username
       end as username
from users u1
    join `all` a  on u1.idu = a.de
    join users u2 on u2.idu = a.para
where
    (a.de = 'ID DO USUARIO LOGADO' AND a.para != 'ID DO USUARIO LOGADO') OR
    (a.de != 'ID DO USUARIO LOGADO' AND a.para = 'ID DO USUARIO LOGADO');
```

[Exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/215cb9/5).

Comment: Eu devo ter me expressado mal, está tudo certo menos "e o outro não, e você quer qualquer um dos dois, certo?" é exatamente o oposto eu desejo pegar o username do usuario oposto ao logado.

Comment: @user3163662 E é exatamente isso que esse código está fazendo! No exemplo, o usuário logado é o "Manuel", então ele retorna "Marcos". Quando eu disse "qualquer um dos dois" eu me referi a qualquer uma das duas situações: onde o usuário logado é o remetente e onde o usuário logado é o destinatário. Mas o que é retornado é sempre o outro usuário, o que não está logado.